# Issues retrieving data and displaying to HTML

Tags: asp.net, database, database-connection

I have followed several tutorials outlining how to read data in from a SQL server and display it on a table in `.cshtml` file. However I am having minimal luck trying to get it populate the table. I feel as though I understand most of what is happening in the code, however this is basically my first attempt in ASP.net(razor pages), and also my first attempt with mySQL with a real database. I have used mongoDB in the past on 1 project and that is the extent of my database usage.

The Issue I am trying to resolve is "Why is my SQL DB data not populating this Table in `HTML.cs`".

I have tried going through and double checking everything I entered for proper letter Casing, I have no **obvious**(to me) errors in my code. I also have added some console outputs to see how far I'm getting before what I expect to happen no longer happens.

First File here is Active Jobs
I have added a few Console`commands to try and see how far it is making it into the code before it stops. The page opens, and I am getting a connection (I believe). however I don't think my`transList`is filling up, and for that matter I'm not sure how to check the contents of`transaction`

I believe my issue will reside in this file.

````
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace CEMDataHub.Pages
    {
    public class ActiveJobsModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<TransactionData> transList = new List<TransactionData>();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("page opened");
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=jbserver\\jbsql;Initial    Catalog=PRODUCTION;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=CEM;Password=****";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("connection opened");
                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Transaction_Data;";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql , connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                TransactionData transaction = new TransactionData();
                                transaction.Id = reader.GetString(0);
                                transaction.Employee = reader.GetString(2);
                                transaction.WorkDate = reader.GetString(3);
                                transaction.TransactionStart = reader.GetString(6);
                                transaction.TransactionEnd = reader.GetString(7);
                                transaction.Job = reader.GetString(14);
                                transaction.Quantity = reader.GetString(16);
                                transaction.PO = reader.GetString(22);
                                transaction.LastUpdated = reader.GetString(24);

                                Console.WriteLine(transaction.Employee);
                                transList.Add(transaction);
                                Console.WriteLine("transaction added to table");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                
            }

        }
    }

    public class TransactionData
    {
        public string Id;
        public string Employee;
        public string WorkDate;
        public string TransactionStart;
        public string TransactionEnd;
        public string Job;
        public string Quantity;
        public string PO;
        public string LastUpdated;
        
    }
    }```


Next we have the html page, or `ActiveJobs.cshtml` file

This one I can't imagine I got something wrong here but its possible. I haven't played with HTML in about 10 years, and a plethora of stuff has likely changed. However as I followed a tutorial for these files, I feel I understand this file almost entirely.

    `@page
    @model CEMDataHub.Pages.ActiveJobsModel
    @{
    }
    <br />
    <h2>Active Transactions</h2>
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee</th>
            <th>Transaction Start</th>
            <th>Job #</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>PO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var transaction in Model.transList)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@transaction.Employee</td>
            <td>@transaction.TransactionStart</td>
            <td>@transaction.Job</td>
            <td>@transaction.Quantity</td>
            <td>@transaction.PO</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    </table>`

In closing, I used the default layout, all I changed there was I added a link to my new page. and I will also add some screenshots of the DB info.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwXXA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnBJg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmrV9.png)
````

Comment: have you tried to debug it? is the connection to `MySQL` established successfully? if there's an exception add it also to the question

Comment: Remove the try/catch from your code. All it's doing is hiding problems from you. An empty catch block is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I have removed the try/catch, and that showed me I had datatype mismatches. corrected that problem.  But now I have a "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null Values." Can I check for null, then react to if its null or not?